# Broken Skeleton grid - 12 and 4 columns

Tags: css, grid, multiple-columns, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm working on my first css framework project based on Skeleton. So far everything went smoothly but it appears that Ive stuck on one thing. Here is the code:

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
        <div class="clear spacernews"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="four columns newspoint">1</div>
            <div class="four columns newspoint">2</div>
            <div class="four columns newspoint">3</div>

    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <h3>Docs &amp; Support</h3>
        <p>The easiest way to really get started with Skeleton is to check out the full docs and info at <a href="http://www.getskeleton.com">www.getskeleton.com.</a>. Skeleton is also open-source and has a <a href="https://github.com/dhgamache/skeleton">project on git</a>, so check that out if you want to report bugs or create a pull request. If you have any questions, thoughts, concerns or feedback, please don't hesitate to email me at <a href="mailto:hi@getskeleton.com">hi@getskeleton.com</a>.</p>
    </div>
```

THe issue is following - when I have only twelve and four columns it works cool. BUT when I nest those 3x four columns newspoint that grid collapse. Why is that? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need three columns, you have the wrong class. Try `one-third column`.

Another thing is that if you add columns into columns you have to add alpha and omega to the first and the last columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "column/columns omega" as wrapper class.

```
<div class="column omega">
        <div class="four columns newspoint">1</div>
        <div class="four columns newspoint">2</div>
        <div class="four columns newspoint">3</div>
</div>
```

That will be fine.